# No introduce datos a la base de datos y sale en navegador datos php

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

tengo un archivo html, cuando registras datos en un da action a un archivo php. Se supone que dentro de un archivo sql no deberia hacer esto cuando le doy a introducir datos. adjunto codigo.

```
    <?php
// ConexiÃ³n a la base de datos
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "nombre_de_usuario";
$password = "contraseÃ±a";
$dbname = "basededatos";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
  die("ConexiÃ³n fallida: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// ObtenciÃ³n de datos del formulario
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$direccion = $_POST["direccion"];
$ciudad = $_POST["ciudad"];
$pais = $_POST["pais"];
$telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$sitio_web = $_POST["sitio_web"];

//
```

---

en registro de php pose esto

```
    <?php
// Conexión a la base de datos
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "nombre_de_usuario";
$password = "contraseña";
$dbname = "hoteles";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
  die("Conexión fallida: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Obtención de datos del formulario
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$direccion = $_POST["direccion"];
$ciudad = $_POST["ciudad"];
$pais = $_POST["pais"];
$telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$sitio_web = $_POST["sitio_web"];

//
```

y en archivo sql esto

```
CREATE TABLE hoteles (
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  direccion VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  ciudad VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  pais VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  telefono VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  sitio_web VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: El código que muestras no ejecuta ninguna sentencia SQL. Sólo abre la conexión, y despliega un mensaje si fracasa. ¿Estás omitiendo código?

Answer (score 0):

El archivo SQL sólo contiene la ***creación*** de la tabla, pero no una consulta de inserción.
Como te comenté, en el de PHP no tienes mas llamada que la de apertura de la conexión, pero no le has agregado un else{} donde realices luego de la apertura exitosa ninguna accion de INSERT o UPDATE.

Por otro lado, un CREATE solo se ejecuta una vez en la BBDD, si lo ejecutas dos veces, disparará un error, y si el usuario de conexión no tiene privilegios (GRANT) de  CREATE, la propia creación no funcionaría. No es aconsejable crear tablas por código programático.

¿Tienes un PHP donde generes el INSERT?

Algo parecido a esto:

```
/* Preparar una sentencia INSERT */
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO myCity (Name, CountryCode, District) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    $sentencia = $mysqli->prepare($consulta);

$sentencia->bind_param("sss", $val1, $val2, $val3);

$val1 = 'Stuttgart';
$val2 = 'DEU';
$val3 = 'Baden-Wuerttemberg';

/* Ejecutar la sentencia */
$sentencia->execute()
```